# Unity v4.0 seems to resolve all dependencies without need for explicit registration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Although I have seen Unity DI in apps before at a previous employer, I am adding it to one for the first time and am effectively a Unity Newbie.  Consequently I am going slowly and testing as I go with Unity v4.0.1.

I have a console app with a simple dependency graph: LoadPayees, which has a dependency on PayeeLogic, which has a dependency on CommissionsRepository.

I have created a very simple Unity registration class with a single method:

```
public class UnityRegistration
{
    public static void RegisterCommissionsTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<ILoadPayees, LoadPayees>();
    }
}
```

One resolution statement:

```
var processorInstance = (BaseTaskProcessor) container.Resolve(Type.GetType(classWithAssembly));
```

where class with assembly resolves to LoadPayees.

I have created a method injector in loadPayees for PayeeLogic:

```
   [InjectionMethod]
    public void Initialize(PayeeLogic payeeLogic)
    {
        this._payeeLogic = payeeLogic;
    }
```

and a constructor injector in PayeeLogic for CommissionsRepository:

```
    private CommissionsRepository _commissionsDal;

    public PayeeLogic(CommissionsRepository commissionsDal)
    {
        this._commissionsDal = commissionsDal;
    }
```

Having created this I then debugged in VS, expecting it to blow up with a null reference exception, since I hadn't explicitly registered PayeeLogic or CommissionsDAL with Unity, but it didn't. The entire process proceeded successfully as it did before I modified it to use Unity.

So either I have missed something stupid (which is likely) or Unity is able to automatically figure out all of LoadPayees' dependencies automatically, which is not what I expected.

So my question to Unity experts is, which of these is more likely?

Comment: Unity can resolve classes without registration.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, once the top level object is registered and resolved with Unity, it can figure out object dependencies, so object injection will work. However, so what. The main point of DI is being able to swap out concrete object instantiation for objects that implement the same interface, so if you want to do that, you need to register and resolve the entire object graph.

I made changes to my code as follows:

```
public static void RegisterCommissionsTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<ILoadPayees, LoadPayees>();
    container.RegisterType<IPayeeLogic, PayeeLogic>();
    container.RegisterType<IPayeeDataAccess, CommissionsRepository>();
    var payeeLogic = container.Resolve<PayeeLogic>();
    var payeeDal = container.Resolve<CommissionsRepository>();
}
```

(LoadPayee resolution unchanged)

```
private IPayeeLogic _payeeLogic;
```

method injection:

```
[InjectionMethod]
public void Initialize(IPayeeLogic payeeLogic)
{
    this._payeeLogic = payeeLogic;
}
```

constructor injection:

```
private IPayeeDataAccess _commissionsDal;

public PayeeLogic(IPayeeDataAccess commissionsDal)
{
    this._commissionsDal = commissionsDal;
}
```

This was very much a newbie question, maybe even a stupid question? Hope it helps another Unity newbie to get their head around this product.

Comment: This is unusual to me as well. There's a downside. If explicit registration is required, you can test the container registration by resolving everything that's registered with it. That doesn't do any good if types being resolved from the container were never registered with it.